# Can a web message call back function be executed before the previous is done executing?

Tags: javascript

If you have web messages which trigger a function and the messages are coming in quickly, can the function be executed before the previous is finished?

```
document.addEventListener('some_message', some_func, false);
function some_func (data){
   //Is the code here always executed before the next function is executed?
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since there's only a single Javascript thread running, only one piece of code can run at a time. So this will always execute in the same order as events are triggered, and only one at a time:

```
function callback_func(data) {
    alert(data);
}
```

However, if your callback works *asynchronously*, i.e. yields the thread back to the browser, then it's unpredictable:

```
function callback_func(data) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        // who knows when this will be called ¯\_(ツ)_/¯
        alert(data);
    }, Math.random());
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks. So my code sample would be the case where it will 'execute in the same order as events are triggered' and therefore not asynchronous?

Comment: Yes, `callback_func` will be triggered in the order that events arrive in and only one at a time. Whatever you do inside there and what may mess up there I don't know… :D

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is the way asynchronous events work in JavaScript.

You can check out [this article](https://blog.sessionstack.com/how-javascript-works-event-loop-and-the-rise-of-async-programming-5-ways-to-better-coding-with-2f077c4438b5), which explains how async-await works in modern JavaScript.

Comment: Any article about how asynchronism works in js to help him to undersand ?